# APEX 5 call modal page from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-5

I work on APEX 5 aplication and want to call Modal Page from Interactive Report. Source of Report looks like

```
select rid, rname, '<div onclick="clickDay('||rid||')">' || day || '</div>'
from ...
```

and clickDay function placed in Header Text looks like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function clickDay(rid){
      window.open("f?p=&APP_ID.:13:&SESSION.::NO::P13_RID:" + rid + ,"Details","dialogWidth:1000px;dialogHeight:600px");
  }
</script>
```

But when I click on IR cell get new page with error
**This page can’t be displayed**
and url looks like **javascript:apex.navigation.dialog('f?p=105:13:9389034907255::NO::P13_RID, ...**

What I do wrong?

Comment: When I change Page 13 Page Mode from Modal to Normal, everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing two different things. You are trying to open a page as a pop up window which is similar to APEX Page Mode, **Non Modal Dialog**. Modal Dialog is different from pop up window, it is embedded inside current page instance. Here is help text from APEX on different page mode,

> **Normal** The page is presented as a normal Application Express application page.
>
> **Modal Dialog** The page is presented as a modal dialog. A modal dialog is an overlay window positioned within the viewport, which
>   remains active and focused until the end user dismisses (closes) it.
>   The underlying page is grayed out and the end user is prevented from
>   interacting with the rest of the page until the dialog is closed.
>
> **Non-Modal Dialog** The page is presented as a non-modal dialog. A non-modal dialog is an overlay window positioned within the viewport,
>   where the end user can interact with the dialog, and content on the
>   page that launched the dialog. A non-modal dialog can be used when the
>   requested information is not essential to continue, work can continue
>   elsewhere while the window is still open.

Comment: Yes, probably you are right, I am new in APEX and am trying to find the way to open already created Page of type Modal Dialog from JavaScript function. Is there a way to open Page 13 from clickDay function?